# Login to remote site using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to integrate a website into my own page. To get acces to the remote site you must to be logged in. The index.php shows how I embed the site using cURL.

**index.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$path = "http://domain.de";
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
curl_exec($curl_handle);


$contents=ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo str_replace('href="/','href="http://domain.de/',str_replace('src="/','src="http://domain.de/',$contents));
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

When I fill out the login-form and submit, I got this error:

```
We received an unexpected status code from the server (404)
```

The problem is that the POST request goes to my site and not the remote.
My question:
How can I post my login-data to the remote site, catch out the response and then use the site on my page? Any help is welcome! (Sorry for my bad description)

Comment: Do you want to login on a different site and then get back to yours? Is that right? You can follow redirect with this option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I want to stay permanently on my site. The different site should be used like an iframe. I use curl because the different site doesn't allow to use iframes for that. FOLLOWLOCATION doesn't have any impacts.

Comment: What are you expecting as a response from the website you are trying to login remotely? What do you want to achieve? Do you need session cookie to make request on a remote website or what?

Comment: The different website is a chatroom. I want to use the chatroom on my site so that I don't need to sites open in my browser. Sorry that I can't tell so much about my problem, I'm new in webprogramming.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make something like this without API provided by a chat service, because something like this is a potential security issue.

Comment: Ok. So as I know such an API doesn't exist yet. Thanks for your help.